# issue with pagination in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

my controller code

```
$posts = Categorie::where('parent_id',$id)->paginate(2);
```

model code :

```
public function post1(){
    return $this->hasMany(post::class, 'category_id');
}
```

view page code :

```
@foreach ($posts as $cat)
    @foreach ($cat->post1 as $post)
        {{Debugbar::info($post->body)}}
        <br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

and for pagination I used code :

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

all are working fine, data is fetched, I checked in the debugger. and pagination link also shown. I have 3 rows then fetched 2 rows on 1 page and other page shows another row. but problem is that it shows all data on page 1 when I clicked on pagination link page2 then shows a blank page.
how my pagination work properly

Comment: Is `$cat->post1` empty for the 2nd page?

Comment: Do you want to paginate categories or posts?

Comment: I want paginate posts

Answer (score 0):

no method "links" you can try this

```
    {{ $posts->render() }}
```

Comment: The links() method is simply an alias for the render() method.But sometimes not work links() method so try render() method.

Comment: same result, nothing change  with render

Answer (score 0):

You are currently paginating categories, not posts.

Define the reverse relationship of `post1` (if you haven't already):

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorie::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Then query the `Post` model and use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('category', function($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('parent_id', $id);
})->paginate(2);

{{ $posts->links() }}
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->body }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: I got this error 
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category does not exist.

Comment: Did you define the reverse relationship? Is it called `category`?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying

Comment: Please add your `Post` model to the question.